# How to use "or" and the adverb "as"?

Tags: conjugation, attachment-ambiguity

The preface of the book, Physics and Music (Dover Publications), states:

> Almost everyone enjoys music, whether as a performer or as a listener.

I was wondering if such a repetition of *as* is necessary (and correct) to convey the intended meaning. Is the following construction grammatical (and preferred instead)?

> Almost everyone enjoys music, whether as a performer or a listener.

And I believe that the determiner *a* is *required* before *both* 'performer' and 'listener'. In other words,... *whether as a performer or listener* is not grammatical. Correct?

Comment: They are both acceptable, though I much prefer the first. Btw, "as" is not a determiner but a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ, I am referring to the repeating _a_ (and not the repeating _as_) and was also wondering if it can be removed, as in `Almost everyone enjoys music, whether as a performer or listener`.

Answer (score -1):

**I** There is no obligation to repeat "as"; the examples shown in Google Books make that clear. The page from which the information has been extracted is "[Google search-whether as a](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)". However, "as" is more often repeated. There is no evident rule that could be inferred from the examples to tell *when* this preposition can be omitted.

[as-1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) Accordingly, anyone involved in the management of public gardens, whether **as a director or area supervisor**, and irrespective of the type and size of such facility, would have to have familiarity with various aspects of garden organization and

[as-2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hefVBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwJHoECFUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false)  Once in psychoanalysis, whether **as a practitioner, a patient or a theoretician**, one is not in hospital anymore, indeed, not in medicine any more – not in any of these medically integrated roles.

[as-3](https://books.google.fr/books?id=OKq2FUXTaUoC&pg=PA146&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwKXoECD4QAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) APO as supply chain DSS; product from company competing with SAP as supply chain transactional ERP From the point of view of any educational treatment of APO, whether **as a classroom delivery or textual reference**, the first case is the

[as-4](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_X5qBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA118&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwNHoECFwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) at a factory or in an office downtown or in a private studio. Your place or type of work doesn't matter to God. What does matter to Him is being in His will (Romans 12:2). You should approach your vocation, whether **as a painter or a plumber**, ...

[as-5](https://books.google.fr/books?id=0S8ikEQfkLEC&pg=PA19&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwPHoECDIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) an elector for having voted or refrained from voting; (B) the receipt of, or agreement to receive, any gratification, whether **as a motive or a reward**—

[as-6](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lugIjqeH1DcC&pg=PA25&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwP3oECAwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false)  whether **as a lost theater ticket or a lost bank note in the same value**; whether **as a gain or a loss**, depending on how you describe the baseline; whether as being an issue of fairness or ordinary market behavior

[as-7](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N0OeAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA904&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwQHoECBMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) When a person enters a culture, whether **as a child or an outsider**, we are confronted by a context that is “overexplained, overdetermined by meaning”

[as-8](https://books.google.fr/books?id=F_I9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA127&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwRHoECBgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) So that now , as regards the parties to an action , it is essential well to ascertain the right to join , as well as the expediency and propriety of joining a person , whether **as a plaintiff or a defendant**, before the commencement of such action ;

[as-10](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Nd6VBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwTXoECBwQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) To be a citizen is to be designated as someone who can participate in these kinds of mechanisms, whether **as a voter or a representative or both**.

[as-11](https://books.google.fr/books?id=HidPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP401&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwW3oECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) An Obliging man, whether **as a master or a servant**, is one of the greatest ornaments to human society.

[as-12](https://books.google.fr/books?id=w2n3Vv0to7kC&pg=PA113&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwXHoECAsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) Schools of thought differ also in how they view the organization of the human being, whether **as a kind of biological organization, a kind of psychological organization or a kind of imported societal organization incorporated from the social**

**II** In addition to the cases "1" and "3" which show the omission of the determiner "a" there are two more  below that can be found in the same source. The determiner "a" is rarely omitted. it seems that at least in some syntactic contexts there is also the possibility to omit the determiner "a".

[a-1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Dri9xTlxkGQC&pg=PA7&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwO3oECDgQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) That power lies in the link from portrait to subject whether **as a world leader or seemingly unknown but loved individual**.

[a-2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=BNxQilrua4sC&pg=PA16&dq=%22whether+as+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi99onJqI7rAhWw3OAKHc6LBNYQ6AEwTnoECCoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22whether%20as%20a%22&f=false) as an historical source, whether **as a witness to the events it describes or as witness to its own values and ideas**.

Comment: Wake me up when you've finished your answer! (only joking).

Comment: @BillJ The google page that provided the examples has now been added; I realize now that one could be curious about the whole of the occurrences of this construction.

Comment: @LPH, you state that `However, "as" is more often repeated. ` and most of the examples you cite actually don't repeat it. So, what gives?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade The examples are provided so as to show that the use without repetition is well established; however the dominant practice consists in repeating the word and you can check that this is so by a perusal of the Google page from which all of this is being deduced.